# Window Function in KDB+

Tags: database, kdb

I am working through an example from [Q for Mortals](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#99-the-update-template) (Section 9.9.9), and cannot understand how the window function is extracting the ask/bid price on the final row.

`aapl 09:30:08 101  104 103 102      103 100 100`

[image]

The window for the last trade @ 09:30:08 (price 101 from `trades` table) should be from 09:30:06 to 09:30:09. This is shown in the `w` variable (last column).

However when I run the window example (verbatim for the book) it includes `ask`of 104 and `bid` of 103. I am not sure why this sample shows up as the timestamp is **09:30:05** which is outside the window range. Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wj` function takes the prevailing quote at the start of each window to be valid for aggregations. If you want to only aggregate what is strictly within your windows use `wj1` which has the same syntax as `wj`.

Jeff Borror demonstrates this later in section 9.9.9 of Q for Mortals.

The internal behavior of `wj` and `wj1` is elaborated on [code.kx.com](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/wj/#interval-behaviour).